# ListView inside ListView + control.Visibility

Tags: wpf, listview, converters, visibility

I'm creating a questionnaire app. My way of doing this is to create a ListView which contains question text and another ListView which contains list af answers(as RadioButtons).
The problem came when there are question which have an answer "Others" which require a TextBox for user to type some text. How can I achieve this? I mean i want to make TextBox visible only when collection of answers contains RadioButton with content "Other".
Below is my xaml code for ListView.

```
<ListView SelectionChanged="myList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding OCquestions}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="20 0 20 0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=questionText}"/>
                    <ListView Name="ListaLista" SelectionChanged="myList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listOfAnswer}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Path=questId}" Content="{Binding Path=answerText}" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"/>                                       
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

// HERE I WANT A TEXTBOX WHICH IS VISIBLE ONLY WHEN listOfAnswer collection contain a RadioButton with Content "Others"

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>      
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I have no idea how to achieve this. I'm not familiar with Converters. Can anyone give me some tip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some Trigger to show/hide the TextBox, something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Path=questId}" 
                    Content="{Binding Path=answerText}" 
                    Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Name="radio"/>
       <TextBox Name="other" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
   </StackPanel>
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding answerText}" Value="Other">
          <Setter TargetName="radio" Property="Content" Value=""/>
          <Setter TargetName="other" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can see that the `DataTrigger` listens to `answerText`, if it's `"Other"` just set the Content of Radio to empty string and set the TextBox's Visibility to `Visible` to show it. This TextBox will be shown on the right of the RadioButton.

Comment: Great it works well. I think i should ask another question but You may help me. I want to disable/enable this textbox while this radiobutton which u called 'radio' is checked or not. Can You help me with this also ?

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out. Thank You very much again.

Answer (score 0):

First add a `ValueConverter`:

```
public abstract class BaseConverter : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class AnswerCollectionToVisibilityConverter : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ICollection<ListOfAnswers> answers = value as ICollection<ListOfAnswers>;
        if (answers != null)
        {
            foreach (Answer answer in answers)
            {
               if (OtherRadioButtonIsHere)
                   return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then add a `TextBox` that uses the `ValueConverter` to set the `Visibility`:

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding Path=listOfAnswer, Converter={AnswerCollectionToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Well it looks very good but i havn't tried it, because first solution filled my needs so i marked first as answer. Thank You for your answer.